# Code coverage with cocoapods library - iOS Unit Test

Tags: cocoapods, code-coverage, xcode8

In Xcode 7, the library for cocoapods library with exclude for the code coverage.

But In Xcode 8, the library will include for code coverage.

Can I had anyway to exclude the library in the code coverage?

Example:
Install pod 'TPKeyboardAvoiding'
TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView.m is include in the code coverage.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to exclude Pods from Code Coverage in Xcode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39674057/how-to-exclude-pods-from-code-coverage-in-xcode)

Answer (score 3):

You should disable the Code Coverage for the Targets that you don't want to be covered. If you want all of your pods to not be included in the code coverage you can add on your podfile

```
#   Disable Code Coverage for Pods projects
post_install do |installer_representation|
   installer_representation.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
       target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['CLANG_ENABLE_CODE_COVERAGE'] = 'NO'
       end
   end
end
```

This will disable the Code Coverage for the target of your Pods like in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5Bsh.png)

If you now run the test with `command + U`

I tried with this pod in one of my project and it worked for me. I'm using Xcode Version 8.1 (8B62)

Anyway, I'm still struggling with the same issue for other pods like [Cartography](https://github.com/robb/Cartography). There's a particular setting (which I didn't discover yet) that it seems to override the `CLANG_ENABLE_CODE_COVERAGE` and the tests still produces the Code Coverage for that.

Let me know if this solve your issue.

Comment: Looks like if the pod is in Swift - it won't be hidden, only ObjC pods are being hidden

Comment: don't forget to run `pod install`